# Return popupmenu selection in MATLAB using one line of code

Tags: user-interface, matlab, popupmenu

I have a GUI which uses a selection from a popupmenu in another callback. Is there a way to return the selected value of the popupmenu in only one line without creating any temporary variables? I've tried several solutions, but I've only managed two lines with one temporary variable:

Three lines:

```
list=get(handles.popupmenu1,'String');
val=get(handles.popupmenu1,'Value');
str=list{val};
```

Two lines:

```
temp=get(handles.popupmenu1,{'String','Value'});
str=temp{1}{temp{2}};
```

Can anyone shave it down to one?

PS, It's a dynamic menu, so I can't just use `get(handles.popupmenu1,'Value')` and ignore the string component altogether.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to shorten it to one line, unless you're simply curious how it could be done. The three-line option is the clearest and easiest to understand, and is the one I would use in any code I wrote.

Comment: @gnovice I was mainly wondering if it can be done. Maybe a mixture of curiosity and annoyance at MATLAB for not having a feature to do it with one get call.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a one-liner:

```
str = getCurrentPopupString(handles.popupmenu1);
```

And here's the definition of `getCurrentPopupString`

```
function str = getCurrentPopupString(hh)
%# getCurrentPopupString returns the currently selected string in the popupmenu with handle hh

%# could test input here
if ~ishandle(hh) || strcmp(get(hh,'Type'),'popupmenu')
error('getCurrentPopupString needs a handle to a popupmenu as input')
end

%# get the string - do it the readable way
list = get(hh,'String');
val = get(hh,'Value');
if iscell(list)
   str = list{val};
else
   str = list(val,:);
end
```

I know that's not the answer you were looking for, but it does answer the question you asked :)

Comment: @Jonas: Touché, for giving me a practical solution to my OCD question.

Comment: You have to remove the logical NOT from strcmp as so:  if ~ishandle(hh) || strcmp(get(hh,'Type'),'popupmenu')

Comment: Despite this being an old answer, it's still very much useful!

I modified the last line the following way for dropdown menus where the String value is non-cell:


    `str = list(val,:);`

Comment: @Josh: Thank you for the heads-up. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

To make it a one-liner, I would simply create my own function (i.e. `getMenuSelection`) like [Jonas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760024/return-popupmenu-selection-in-matlab-using-one-line-of-code/2760117#2760117) illustrates in his answer. If you *really* want a true one-liner, here's one using [CELLFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/cellfun.html):

```
str = cellfun(@(a,b) a{b},{get(handles.popupmenu1,'String')},{get(handles.popupmenu1,'Value')});
```

*Very* ugly and hard to read. I'd definitely go with writing my own function.

**EDIT:** And here's a slightly shorter (yet still equally ugly) one-liner using [FEVAL](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/feval.html):

```
str = feval(@(x) x{1}{x{2}},get(handles.popupmenu1,{'String','Value'}));
```

Comment: +1 for giving me the answer that I actually wanted, however impractical it may be

Answer (score 5):

I know this is stupid, but I couldn't resist:

```
list=get(handles.popupmenu1,'String'); str=list{get(handles.popupmenu1,'Value')};
```

I know that's not what you meant, but like the other answers above, it does answer your question... :-)